# Twitter & Facebook JSON feed without authentication

Tags: android, json, facebook, twitter

Hi I am looking for Twitter and Facebook URL's which returns JSON feed timeline of user without any authentication. I know Twitter new rules has deprecated old APIs which now requires authentication. But i know there are some third party APIs on server which makes it easy for user to just make do things with simple URLs.

Do anyone has tried any such cases.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find such functionality now.  The authentication isn't just for locking down the security of a given feed; it's for tracking and throttling the usage by each user.  Places like Facebook and Twitter are fearful that (with enough API freedom) they will render their own sites useless and reduce advertisement revenue, among a slew of other reasons.

Comment: Thanks Steiner, But I do not agree as i myself have used some cURL recipes in past which were really easy but unfortunately i do not have code for that. But thanks for helping

Comment: Exactly; in the past. They've both locked down their APIs... mainly from each-other, lol.